# RACSignal combine

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a RACCommand that uses this signal:

```
- (RACSignal *)getProductsSignal {
  return [[RACSignal combineLatest:@[self.currentCategorySignal, self.client.getProducts] reduce:^id(Category *category, NSArray *products) {
    return [[products.rac_sequence filter:^BOOL(Product *product) {
      return [product belongsToCategory:category];
    }] array];
  }];
}
```

The problem im having is that the signal never sends complete, so, the button that is binded with the command will be disabled after the first press forever.

```
- (RACSignal *)currentCategorySignal {
  return RACObserve(self, currentCategory);
}
```

getProducts looks something like this

```
- (RACSignal *)getProducts {
  NSString *path = @"/products"];

  return [[[[self.manager rac_GET:path parameters:nil]
  replayLazily]
  parseResponseForClass:[TPProduct class]]
  transformError];
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that `take:` signal operator could be used here. It returns a signal which completes as soon as the original signal sends `n` next values:

```
- (RACSignal *)getProductsSignal {
  return [[RACSignal combineLatest:@[self.currentCategorySignal, self.client.getProducts] reduce:^id(Category *category, NSArray *products) {
    RACSignal *productsSignal = [[products.rac_sequence filter:^BOOL(Product *product) {
      return [product belongsToCategory:category];
    }] array];
  }];
  [return productsSignal take:1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was with RACObserve. RACObserve only sends complete when the object is deallocated.

Had to change my signals to perform the task I wanted.